# エディタで開発したPHP（.html）の一連を、ECLIPSEの管理に移行したい

Tags: php, eclipse

皆様　いつも大変お世話になっております。

自身の開発端末Windows7は、既にApache2.4とPHPを設定済み（XAMPPによる）で
[http://localhost/XXXX/成果物.htmlで](http://localhost/XXXX/%E6%88%90%E6%9E%9C%E7%89%A9.html%E3%81%A7)、相応の動作が達成されています（画面遷移も）。

この端末に本日ECLIPSEをインストールしました。海外サイトのページからでしたが、一応にPHP用途のものが入った認識です．．．．

さてECLIPSEについて全く無知なので、ご教示を頂けませんでしょうか？？

エディタで作成したスクリプト=PHPのファイル（拡張子=html）一連を、PHPのプロジェクトとして管理していきたいと考えています。
ステップ実行がこちらのユーティリティでできると聞いたこと、エディタで開発作業をしていることが一般的でないような気がしてきたためです（ECLIPSEの他の恩恵を知らない）。

**質問**
プロジェクトの作成まで完了しました。
例えば、作成済みのlogon.htmlというファイルを、このプロジェクト配下の管理にする=ECLIPSE上で開くには、どういった操作を具体的に行えば良いのでしょうか？

開発端末のWebサイト（htdocs/ｘｘｘｘｘ/)内の実ファイルと別管理になっても良いとも考えますが、常識的には同一管理とすべきなのでしょうか？ディプロイ操作をすることで、サイトへの移行を達成していくが一般的なのでしょうか

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずは本家のEclipseプロジェクトのドキュメントを参照することが大事かと思います。
https://www.eclipse.org/documentation/

Eclipse自体の使い方「Workbench User Guide」の項目
EclipseのPHPプラグインの使い方「PHP Developer User Guide」の項目を
それぞれ参照にすると良いでしょう。

> 開発端末のWebサイト（htdocs/ｘｘｘｘｘ/)内の実ファイルと別管理になっても良いとも考えますが、常識的には同一管理とすべきなのでしょうか？ディプロイ操作をすることで、サイトへの移行を達成していくが一般的なのでしょうか

こちらは何を達成したいかによります。
例えば開発端末を操作するのはエンジニアだけではなくテスターやプロマネが利用する場合は、わりと品質が高めのプロダクトが求められるので開発途中のものと区別して、デプロイ環境を用意したりします。
デプロイ環境の用意自体にもコストが掛かるので
特に制約がなければまずはご自身のやり方でやってみてはどうでしょうか？